# audio.SE is ailing

Tags: discussion, area-51, audio

Have you guys checked [audio.SE A51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4/audio-recording-and-production)? It's in bad shape. I also checked [how it compares with the other sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) (using Default sorting) and it's near the bottom, and it's been at least a month in existence. Is there a risk it might be closed?

Comment: I know the "dupe" is newer, but it will answer this question, and has a more general application.  This is pretty localized.

Comment: I really hope it doesn't close.  I've found it to be a very useful resource, and feel that it fills a huge void in the audio community.  Trouble is, I don't know how we get that community to find us.

Comment: [It](https://audio.stackexchange.com/) has been shut down now: *"Couldn't find site. The Q&A site you are looking for doesn't seem to exist…yet."*

Comment: It is now [effectively *sound.stackexchange.com*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87052/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-headphone-repair#comment1277408_87052) (a merge and then [a split/merge](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357/moving-avp-to-video-se-next-steps) three years later in 2014... *[Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/tour)*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The criteria for determining the success or failure of a site has been discussed (recently) here: [What are the success criteria ... ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76338/what-are-the-success-criteria-for-an-area-51-beta-proposal/76392#76392)

The *-literal-* answer to your question is *sure, it can be closed.* But I imagine you should be asking *what can be done about it?* The place to pose that question is to the Audio-SE community — on [their meta](http://meta.audio.stackexchange.com). That's what a community's meta site is for; To [work out these questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) while the site is still early in beta.

Comment: I thought of posting there, but I wanted a bigger community to comment. (maybe even a call to arms... let's rescue the site :-)

Comment: @Tshepang: I can appreciate your reasons, but having each site ask their "7 essential" questions here isn't really sustainable. Nor would it work to allow promotions (come use our site, come up-vote my question, etc, etc) to carry over to here. The question *should* be closed as off topic, but it collaterally addresses a larger issue that may help other communities, so I left it open.

Comment: @Tshepang: We'd welcome your input: http://meta.audio.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-do-we-promote-our-site