# What are the success criteria for an Area 51 beta site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-phase

In other words, what determines the future of a Beta site, i.e. which path it goes down:

- beta is closed (failure) or
- beta becomes a public live site with its own artwork (success)

And what is the timeline for this?

On the [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) I read, *"If the site does not get used, it will be deleted."* but I'm missing *how* that decision is made.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "success criteria" is outlined in detail in this blog post:

[**When Will My Site Graduate?**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)

But here's the gist.

A site will stay in beta for at least 90 days. After 90 days, it becomes eligible for graduation as a full site. A site will graduate when it has:

1. Established a critical mass of "experts" so that there is a reasonable expectation that your question will be answered (+90% according to the [Area 51 analytics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338?phase=beta)).
2. Reached a level of maturity to become a self-sustaining, community-moderated site (+10 users with +2,000 rep, 5 users with +3,000 rep).
3. Reach a critical mass of users where the traffic indicates strong, sustainable growth.

If the site has not reached these goals by 90 days in beta, it can remain a beta site as long as it continues to show steady progress. But if the beta site is showing a general, unrecoverable, downward trend, [it may be closed as inviable](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/).

Comment: yep, that's a clear answer thank you. Particularly interesting to me is the grace period after 90 days in beta, as long as the site is showing progress.

Comment: Is there a definition of steady progress?

Comment: @Belinda It's pretty obvious when a site has stopped making "steady progress" because it is typically followed by a precipitous drop in a key metric such as % answered questions and daily visits. Steady progress means that the site continues to receive high-quality questions and that users have a reasonable high expectation expectation that their questions will be answered. We've never had to precisely define "steady progress" because the drop that follows is *SO* obvious, that it is hard to miss.

Comment: I'd expected that if the worrying or OK stats did not go up for a while that it may not count as steady progress but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like possibly a 90 day evaluation period after launch.  If you look at beta's sites toward the top right on Area 51 there is message similar to this:

> This site is in
>
> Public Beta Anyone can participate!
>
> The site's progress will be evaluated
>   in 70 days.

Once 90 days hits, there is a set of criteria at the top of the page that shows whether a site is doing Excellent, Okay, or Worrying.

However, I am not sure if the final decision is manual or not based on this criteria.