# Why is German Language and Usage still in beta?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, graduating-sites

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76338/what-are-the-success-criteria-for-an-area-51-beta-site), our site has the three factors mentioned there. Here is [its status on area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413?page=1&phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top): 
[image]

The only problem is the number of questions per day which I believe is caused by remaining a long time in beta phase. See also the site stats:

[image]

Comment: Where's the "visits/day" stat?

Comment: @jadarnel27: Added.

Comment: Hi Gigili, sorry for highjacking this question of yours. I saw that you left GL&U - that's a pity! Any chances of convincing you to come back? (Please leave me just a short note if you don't want to discuss it.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Thank you for your very kind comment. I'd come back but I can't stand something there, so I doubt it. But thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gigili: Is it this discussion about downvoting, closing questions and everything? I'd be happy if you chose to ignore that business, but I fully understand if you say it bothers you too much.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: It's about everything and what you said, yes. I've done much effort to keep the site alive but they simply don't deserve it. I learned enough German thanks to GLU, For the time I don't have any special questions to ask or any answer to post. Thank you, so kind of you.

Comment: @Gigili: Thanks a lot for letting me know, and all the best to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an occasional user on GL&U, I've wondered the same thing from time to time.

IMHO the one statistic that needs improvement is the most important.  3 questions per day is just not even close to getting it done.  There aren't enough questions popping up to justify frequent visits, and since so few total questions have been asked (about 1000) there isn't that much content available for prospective users to peruse.

Hopefully we can get this turned around!

Comment: I think this is the biggest one for me.  I participate on [music.se] (beta as well), but I often don't visit because there is so little new content.

Answer (score 7):

Graduation is not decided solely based on those statistics you see, there are other factors the SE team evaluates when deciding whether to graduate a site or not.

One important one that  I have seen mentioned a few times on different beta sites is that they look for a steady upwards trend in traffic. The [traffic of GL&U looks more like it's going sideways at the moment](http://www.quantcast.com/german.stackexchange.com/traffic/), so that might be a factor that is hindering graduation.

Comment: Great to know that. Is there anything we as GLU active users can do about it? How long will it take?

Comment: You'll have to wait for the SE team to respond to get an official answer. But I'd try to get more (good) content on the site, which should also increase the traffic from search engines. And promoting the site is of course also useful. SE has become increasingly strict about graduating sites, take a look at other beta sites and you'll see quite some with better stats that haven't graduated yet.