# Are closed sites ever archived?

Tags: support, area-51, closed-sites, archive

A site may be on a very specialized topic, and may open and get some good questions and answers but not enough to satisfy the SE rules for keeping a site open.

For example, on the [**Podcast #68 blog page**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/stack-exchange-podcast-68-a-badger-a-horse-and-a-dik-dik-the-documentation-episode/?cb=1) it says

> We had an Arabic site at time of recording, but it's closed due to low activity levels

I understand why a site may be closed. I see that addressed here: **[Why close SE sites with low activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132945/why-close-se-sites-with-low-activity)**

But I'd like to know if they are ever archived.

It seems to me that for a domain of knowledge that is very specialized and doesn't have lots of contributors, or frequent usage, but has content that is valuable to the people posting it and many readers of the site (even if not to SE), then Usenet is safer, because at least that is fully archived by Google (to the extent that Google can be trusted to keep an archive).

Comment: partly related will add https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266749/what-does-an-italicized-username-mean-in-a-chat-room-and-how-much-can-a-room-ow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We release a data dump (in XML format) of every closed site. They are linked from the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) proposal for the site:

[image]

Anyone is welcome to download it for their own use or set it up on the web somewhere so long as the [content license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) is respected.

<sub>(Our attribution requirements are clarified [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). I am not a lawyer, but I would imagine it'd be fine to just mention that the content originally came from a particular Stack Exchange site since linking back to the original is no longer possible once the site has been shut down.)</sub>

Comment: For how long is the data dump being hosted? Permanently?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes.