# When do beta sites get a custom look?

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase, beta-sites

I'm asking this because the [graphic design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) site has been in public beta for 838 days and is still using the default beta-site theme which seems quite inappropriate for a site full of graphical designers.

Comment: They get custom design only when becoming full member in the network i.e. public beta is over.

Comment: When do sites go out of beta?

Comment: Site is launched as part of the network when the [Stack Exchange employee responsible for this](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/users/5/robert-cartaino) manually confirms it's ready and when the design is ready. I read somewhere that Area51 is going to be changed into something totally different so they're probably waiting until this change is completed before launching new sites.

Comment: However two years in Beta sounds indeed way too much, feel free to ask on [Area 51 Discussion site](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Mr D, the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) has a little more info about the beta period for new SE sites.

Comment: Related: [What are the success criteria for an Area 51 beta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76338/152859)

Comment: Here's an idea, create a Firefox or Chrome theme to overlay the site with a custom design.  Host it on the web store, link it in on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com), then ask the Graphics Design mods to put a link to that page in the FAQ for anyone who wants the new theme.  **Disclaimer:** I'm a mod on other sites, and I personally wouldn't put a link to a theme in our FAQ, but Graphics Design is a little different situation. The point about the lack of design on a design site is of course odd and ironic.

Comment: @gnat this question is much older, if anything it's the other way around

Comment: [question age doesn't matter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/165773)

Comment: @gnat When the newer question was asked, this question had more and better answers. You can make the argument that the scope of that question is broader and adresses more things but in that case you can't argue that this question is a duplicate. Either way, at the time none seemed notice or care about the similarity of these questions so none of them were moderated. In other words, my question is being marked as a duplicate because of subpar moderation when a newer question was asked. Or are the questions different and therefore not duplicates? Let me know so I can decide what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beta sites don't get custom looks until sometime after they exit the beta period.  As beta sites, they get a default beta look, which is plain as you have noted.  See the [Graphic Design FAQ](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq#sketchy) for more info.

In the long run (i.e. after the beta period), yes, the plain look would be quite ironic for a graphic-design site. :)