# How does a mature Stack Exchange site get its customized design?

Tags: support, design

Is there any kind of documentation about how a Stack Exchange site that has left beta is being customized? Is this done by the people starting the new site, or by Stack Exchange itself?

Comment: Well. Those questions appear to be about per/user styling. My question is about changing the default look of a new site.

Comment: I don't understand. Who will change then? A single user will be able to change the design for all other users??

Comment: AskUbuntu for example looks totally different from SO. How is that done?

Comment: @OliverWeichhold [Jin, a Stack exchange employee](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147574/jin) designs it as part of the site's graduation from beta.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Okay, now I get it. All SE site customization is done by SE itself and not by the people starting a new site!?

Comment: @OliverWeichhold in the current system, yes.  There was a now dead scenerio where someone would actually own their own site and in that case, they would be responsible for the design and many other aspects of the site,  but that was killed off several years ago.  In fact the last remaining sites that were user owned were finally pulled back under the Stack Exchange umbrella over the last year.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thank you very much. I suggest you migrate your comment into an answer which I can accept.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold it is closed as a duplicate, you cannot add answers to closed questions.  I suggest you edit your question to make it more clear what you are asking since your original question was quite unclear.  Then it may get reopened, however, I think there is a different duplicate on the design process itself, I just can't find it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 reopened. Did you mean [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87220/who-are-the-artists-and-designers-doing-the-stack-exchange-sites-excellent-artw)? While not 100% dupe, the question itself answers this question here.

Comment: @Sha must be. I had thought there was an exact. Dup somewhere but this is the best one on I found http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177407/when-do-beta-sites-get-a-custom-look but that is more. Maybe this should stay open and get a complete answer

Comment: @psubsee2003 well, your comment above is good enough in my opinion, feel free to turn it into an answer. :-)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Confirmed dupe of the question you've mentioned.