# Where can I ask questions about headphone repair?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I'm currently experiencing a problem with my headphones (some parts of the audio aren't coming through), and before sending them in for repair, I thought I'd do a little debugging myself, but it's too hard for me (possibly because I have no experience whatsoever in sound equipment). Is there somewhere on Stack Exchange I can ask a question about this problem?

It seems to be off-topic on [Audio.SE](http://audio.stackexchange.com), which is about audio recording and production, not general audio equipment.

Super User, similarly, seems to be a bit of a stretch—although it seems to be where most of the questions about headphones have gone historically, it's not really a computer problem, since the same problem happens when plugged into mobile devices, etc.

Basically, I'd like to know if there's an Stack Exchange site I'm not aware of, or, if not, if it's actually on topic on Audio or Super User.

Comment: It seems a shame to use such a generic term like "audio" for such a narrow field.

Comment: there is some questions about headphones at gaming - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=headphone

Comment: brb proposing headphones.SE on 51

Comment: http://audio.stackexchange.com/ doesn't exist: *"Couldn't find site. The Q&A site you are looking for doesn't seem to exist…yet."*. It did exist: *[audio.SE is ailing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76322/)*

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum looks like it was just renamed: https://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: From [the Area 51 site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4/audio-recording-and-production): *"merged with* ***Video and Film Production*** *on 2011-06-06T002700"*. Apparently now *"[Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/tour)"*

Comment: Yes, more details also [here](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357/moving-avp-to-video-se-next-steps).

Comment: @Shadow The Kid Wizard: So they merged in audio in 2011 and killed it off in the 2014? No, *"Sound is now, for the most part, moved over to Sound Design SE"*.

Comment: *[Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/tour)*: *"Sound Design Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for sound designers, engineers, producers, editors, and audio production enthusiasts."*. The original's was *"... for engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts spanning the fields of audio, video, and media creation."*

Comment: So *audio.stackexchange.com* seems more or less equivalent to *sound.stackexchange.com*.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum yes, you're probably correct.

Answer (score 3):

[Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq) seems to be the best place for now. Just don't phrase it as a support question.

> and it is not about …
> ...
> consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, **except when designing these products or hacking their electronics for other uses**

See: [iPod headphone jack only driving one side - is there an easy way to fix this?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5841/ipod-headphone-jack-only-driving-one-side-is-there-an-easy-way-to-fix-this)

Comment: Still a bit of a stretch

Comment: A lead for repair question there: *[Repair Questions: Suggestions for a Policy](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/684/repair-questions-suggestions-for-a-policy)*

Comment: Based on the quote you provided yourself I don't see how this is a valid answer.